# Group List of Objects to Create an Extended Object List

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have these sample records from database which is a result of group by query:

```
[
 {
   "name": "Troy",
   "acct": 1123,
   "type": " Savings",
   "total": 50
 },
 {
   "name": "Larry",
   "acct": 4233,
   "type": " Savings",
   "total": 200
 },
 {
   "name": "Troy",
   "acct": 1123,
   "type": " Current",
   "total": 120
 },
 {
   "name": "Larry",
   "acct": 4233,
   "type": " Current",
   "total": 220
 }
]
```

Now, i need to create a report that looks like so:

```
[
 {
   "name": "Troy",
   "acct": 1123,
   "totalSavings": 50,
   "totalCurrent": 120
 },
 {
   "name": "Larry",
   "acct": 4233,
   "totalSavings": 200,
   "totalCurrent": 220
 }
]
```

.

```
public class DbTrans {
    private String name;
    private String acct;
    private String type;
    private double total;

// getters and setters
...
}
```

I have tried using some lambda techniques like the one below, but i'm still not getting close to the solution i desire.

```
 Map<String, List<DbTrans>> collect = transList.stream().collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.getType()));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the response Dto is not the same as the request Dto, what I suggest is to create a new Response class lests call it:

```
public class DbTransResponse {
    private String name;
    private String acct;
    private double totalSavings;
    private double totalCurrent;
    // getters and setters
}
```

then the result can be like so :

```
List<DbTransResponse> result = transList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DbTrans::getAcct))
        .values().stream()
        .map(trans -> new DbTransResponse(
                trans.get(0).getName(),
                trans.get(0).getAcct(),
                trans.get(0).getTotal(),
                trans.get(1).getTotal()
        )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I consider that the list should contain two entries of each name so the you can get `totalSavings` from the first entry `trans.get(0).getTotal()` and `totalCurrent` from the second `trans.get(1).getTotal()`.

If you are not sure you can use conditions to fill your object for example you can check if there are two elements if not set a default value.

---

[**Ideone demo**](https://www.ideone.com/JJIBy3)

**Outputs**

```
DbTransResponse{name='Larry', acct='4233', totalSavings=200.0, totalCurrent=220.0}
DbTransResponse{name='Troy', acct='1123', totalSavings=50.0, totalCurrent=120.0}
```

Comment: It may be that I am working with banking :) but if the type is transaction type your consideration is wrong and there may be multiple transactions of a type. But that the Olantobi should answer.

Comment: By the way, there is no point into grouping by Name. Account is uniquely associated to a Person. Therefore grouping by accountnumber is enough. Unless it is not the owner of the account but the transaction originator which I doubt.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I agree with the second comment, group by account is better, and about the first comment, if the OP want to group with multiple fields then its not more easy to do `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DbTrans::getName,
        Collectors.groupingBy(DbTrans::getAcct)))
.values().stream()
.flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Collectors::toMap` for this purpose (with a single `collect` operation)

```
 Map<Integer, DbTransResponse> collect = transList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(DbTrans::getAcct, 
                                      DbTransResponse::new, 
                                      DbTransResponse::merge));

 Collection<DbTransResponse> result = collect.values();
```

here is merge method in `DbTransResponse` class

```
static DbTransResponse merge(DbTransResponse r1, DbTransResponse r2) {
        return new DbTransResponse(
                r1.name, r1.acct,
                r1.totalSavings + r2.totalSavings,
                r1.totalCurrent + r2.totalCurrent
        );
    }
```

and an additional constructor for `DbTransResponse` class, though you can move this logic to a method

```
DbTransResponse(DbTrans dbTrans) {
   this.name = dbTrans.getName();
   this.acct = dbTrans.getAcct();
   this.totalSavings = "Savings".equals(dbTrans.getType()) ? dbTrans.getTotal() : 0;
   this.totalCurrent = "Current".equals(dbTrans.getType()) ? dbTrans.getTotal() : 0;
```

}

[**demo**](https://tio.run/##rVVNj5swEL3zKywuGC1FCdteiKK22vZQqdtKTW5tD17izZISoLahWq3y27NjMGATQ1V1uUBm5s3Mm68cSE1eHXa/zuf0WBZMoAMIwkqkWcgFo@QY3hRZRhNRML5ypmw2zWvlOGV1l6UJSjLCObolaY6eHAfBoxRcEAGvukh36AhqDMg033//iQjbcx@skXpqwpBgJOckEWmRc7RGbZSwuMe9lXxy@gd9uNtKW@xuWfHoBmi5jK4D5G5IDd45CN4s/GAa9ZkwJmGvo2sTFi1mcWa0m4oxmgspiP4lXI@LANaj/JVjFINRXmUCyqBXJUza7uChS6EobkmJVbA43lPxPklE0IX/RnkJSBrHkJNFeqRsT309ehs5rElWUY798L5gH0nygDePXFDoRyXiuIQ2iiwHmEScWrDqdjsNo0BaqwFbE0FROwsoJ0e6ulB@ygXdU4YIcLnU7gqYL4pEIUimujdvpGqusRzlh7VsAiN6YIsW2Lzr8ywf8ZDyUDqELpose60MAFqTZa/VI8pJsNI1rVUqnXXPu7M8TVdA/Ua79j3HRpmEMGxfQIL9aWqaqZxLq@mIZ7@QIf1dkYxjzcf2sYRwPnqrO95KPPZRjBZ/r0u/f//lXaujGvvxwDeLhcdStrzYQcSica0ZFRXL9SvSd8mw6@2XYTu48NHM7JSVUekriGxI5mFdCQeYkhgo31qjd19ryli6o8OWtv8Qau1E0X7giUq4ozI8uZCGKzmvPfnZzOUV8n54nlQEzUatpaYZw0akM21UusDKfIAppgNsKIZ38nTKivjkQXzZQ9iVD@Z2/gBeXr65i6e5NS/dy584CCGPlUHAXN3ullkHS2XaH6KJRTJS0@Ad7f462fFm8tbw7emww012GlyVVjsydvyYvnJzOp@fAQ)